# How to execute code at specific time

Tags: android

I'm trying to do an app that can execute some code at specific time (like a service) but time must be changed and setup by the app.

I don't want the whole answer, but i'm newbie, and if anybody knows the good way to acomplish it, and maybe some references i'll be very grateful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

[Jeff Sharkey's android-sky App Widget](http://code.google.com/p/android-sky/) includes an example of scheduling code to run at a certain time.  It uses an [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Alarm Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).